# Math mode \nZeta symbol

Tags: math-mode

[image]

Hello,

Can someone help me, thanks!

Comment: Please make your question more suitable (such as remove "thanks!")

Comment: Unicode has a combining-vertical-overlay character, U+20D2 or `\vertoverlay`, but there doesn’t seem to be any math font that displays it the way you want over a capital letter.

Comment: I feel like this question fails to ask a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\nZeta{\raisebox{0.8pt}{$\vert$}\mkern-7.75mu\mathsf{Z}}
\begin{document}
$\nZeta$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, just what i needed! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

The amount of shifting of the bar has been computed precisely, under the assumption that the main letter sits on the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nZeta}{\mathord{\mathpalette\nZeta@\relax}}
\newcommand{\nZeta@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$#1|$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$#1Z$}%
  \dimen@=\dimexpr(\dp\z@-\ht\z@+\ht\tw@)/2\relax
  \vphantom{\raisebox{\dimen@}{$\m@th#1|$}}% keep the bounding box
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth\raisebox{\dimen@}{$\m@th#1|$}\hidewidth\cr
    $\m@th#1\mathsf{Z}$\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\nZeta b_{a\nZeta b}$

\end{document}
```

The symbol scales in subscripts and superscripts. Change `\mathord` to the real meaning of your symbol.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As shown, will work in all math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\nZeta{\mathord{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\SavedStyle|}{\SavedStyle\mathsf{Z}}}}}}
\begin{document}
$x\nZeta y_{\nZeta_{\nZeta}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]